# Spring boot H2 console returns 404

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have a simple Springboot application and it's up running. I am able to call REST endpoints through Postman. However, when I try to access the console using http://localhost:8080/h2 it keeps returning 404.

```
2020-08-29 08:06:37.577  INFO 6507 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [

        name: default

        ...]

2020-08-29 08:06:37.644  INFO 6507 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}

2020-08-29 08:06:37.645  INFO 6507 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

2020-08-29 08:06:37.677  INFO 6507 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}

2020-08-29 08:06:37.787  INFO 6507 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

2020-08-29 08:06:38.247  INFO 6507 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

2020-08-29 08:06:38.737  INFO 6507 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup

2020-08-29 08:06:38.738  INFO 6507 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure

2020-08-29 08:06:38.741  INFO 6507 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]

2020-08-29 08:06:38.813  INFO 6507 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.ipc.netty.tcp.BlockingNettyContext     : Started HttpServer on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080

2020-08-29 08:06:38.813  INFO 6507 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080

2020-08-29 08:06:38.816  INFO 6507 --- [           main] c.v.t.c.m.tenant.discovery.Application   : Started Application in 3.4 seconds (JVM running for 3.661)

2020-08-29 08:06:48.527  WARN 6507 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [GET http://localhost:8080/h2]: Response status 404

2020-08-29 08:23:07.301  WARN 6507 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Retrograde clock change detected (housekeeper delta=29s626ms), soft-evicting connections from pool.

2020-08-29 08:57:06.586  WARN 6507 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=33m59s284ms).

2020-08-29 09:35:49.699  WARN 6507 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper
```

My application.yml file looks like this.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
    platform: h2
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 50
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
server:
  port: 8080
```

Comment: Can you post full logs.

Comment: I added more logs

Answer (score 10):

As per your logs, I found that, you are using an embedded server, other than tomcat, i.e, `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty` that comes along with spring webflux dependency.

`H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration` will not be executed for spring webflux & netty(reactor based), as H2 console will only be available to **servlet based applications**. So, you have to configure H2 server manually in this spring boot application, with spring webflux & netty.

Sample H2Server (working code):

```
package com.example.springbootnettyserver;

import org.h2.tools.Server;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import static org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer;

    @Component
    public class H2ServerManual {
    
            Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(H2ServerManual.class);
            private Server webServer;
    
            @Value("${h2-server.port}")
            Integer h2ConsolePort;
    
            @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
            public void start() throws java.sql.SQLException {
                log.info("starting h2 console at port "+ h2ConsolePort);
                this.webServer = createWebServer("-webPort", h2ConsolePort.toString(),
                                                 "-tcpAllowOthers").start();
                System.out.println(webServer.getURL());
            }
    
            @EventListener(ContextClosedEvent.class)
            public void stop() {
                log.info("stopping h2 console at port "+h2ConsolePort);
                this.webServer.stop();
            }
    }
```

**Note**: `org.h2.tools.Server` class will be resolved only when h2 dependency is added without scope of runtime. (remove scope element in dependency)

In application.properties, you will add port details for h2 server like

```
h2-server:
 port: 8081
```

Here, now, the H2 console will be available at http://localhost:8081

Following properties can be removed

```
#  h2:
#    console:
#      enabled: true
#      path: /h2
#      settings:
#        web-allow-others: true
```

For Reference: https://github.com/donthadineshkumar/webflux-netty-server-h2-example.git